# Custom Visual Force page access for standard button

Tags: visualforce, button

I have two profiles named as Recruiter and Manager,for these two objects, i am overwriting standard new button with custom Visual force page

I need for one profile custom Vf page for **New** button and another profile for No Override(use default) functionality for **New** Button

> How to Restrict Profile Based access for Overriding Functionality in
>   salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `action` attribute on the VF page to call a function in your controller that redirects users that should not use the override to the default New-screen. You can use the `nooverride` GET parameter to prevent the action override.

Your function could look something like this:

```
public PageReference redirect(){
    PageReference pr;
    String currentProfile = someFunctionToGetProfile()
    if(currentProfile == 'Profile That Needs Normal New Page'){
         //replace 000 with the actual object prefix that you need
         pr = new PageReference('/000/e?nooverride=1');
    }
    return pr;
}
```

Comment: we can restrict system administrator profile also @rael_kid

Comment: Good Suggestion, can you ellaborate the solution with controller also

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can extend the check `currentProfile == 'Profile That Needs Normal New Page'` to any number of different profile names. I don't know how to elaborate any further though